# does input value contain any the following

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to have the text hide if the input value contains any letters of the following (and only matching letters). Currently it is triggered by any letter and not only those in the word 'england' and i dont understand why. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input1")

$("#input1").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("input").submit();
  }
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if ($("input[value*='england']")) {
    $('#etext').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search.. ." />
<p id="etext">England</p>
```

Comment: I don't understand why your code has toooooooo many spaces.

Comment: important to understand that the value attribute will not reflect user input but the value property will. Also `if($(selector))` will always be truthy since `$()` returns an object even if no match is found

Comment: @charlietfl Added your point into my answer. Thanks. `:D`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a right check:

```
if ($("input[value*='england']")) {
```

You need to change that with:

```
if ($("input").val().toLowerCase().indexOf("england") === 0) {
```

The above code:

- Gets the current value of `<input>`.
- Converts into lower case.
- Checks if the index of `england` is the starting one.

And the same way, you don't need to mix up pure JavaScript and jQuery. Use the same code, and enclose everything inside `document`'s `ready` event.

```js
$(function() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input1");

  $("#input1").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("input").submit();
    }
  });

  $("#input1").on("keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("england") === 0) {
      $('#etext').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search.. ." />
<p id="etext">England</p>
```

**Note:** It is important to understand that the value attribute will not reflect user input but the value property will. Also `if ($(selector))` will always be truthy since $() returns an object

Finally, please end the statements with a semicolon `;`. Good practise.

Comment: Much appreciated and definitely what i was looking for, however as a follow up question is it possible to hide the text if the input value is only equal to some parts of 'england'. For eksample if i type 'eng' then the text would hide, but if i type engfx then it would not.

Comment: @JohnK Yes, just change the `england` to `eng`. And for the second one, I guess you need to implement in a different way.

Comment: @JohnK Source: http://jsbin.com/qimagufipe/edit?html,css,js Enjoy... `:D`